# Running UI test in Jenkins Docker-Slave

Tags: eclipse, docker, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-docker, window-tester

With the use of Jenkins [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) we can provision the slaves dynamically.

My need is to run UI tests on the automatically created slaves. Is that feasible? If yes, how can we achieve that?

UI tests are WindowTester test cases for eclipse based tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing same kind of stuff, On successful build we are running all automated test cases on windows machine.

In your Jenkins, you need to add Windows machine as a Slave machine.

Try below tutorial -
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows

Once node is up and running then in your Job make sure you selected windows slave node.

[image]

Comment: This is simple & straight forward general case. My scenario is different. I am provisioning Jenkins slaves automatically on runtime using Docker Plugin.

Comment: This might help you. https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/jenkins-ephemeral-docker-tutorial